# How do I set up to has_many/belongs_to assocations so that only one combination is allowed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have three tables, applicants, users and ratings.  The basic idea is that each applicant gets assigned a rating by any number of users.  This part I have working without any problems.  However, if a user goes to edit their rating (which includes a score), the form adds a second rating.  I need to change things so that each user can only assign one rating for a given applicant.

```
class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :ratings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ratings, :allow_destroy => true

class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many  :ratings
```

The rating table just contains an applicant_id, a user_id and a score.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :applicant
  validates_uniqueness_of :applicant_id, :scope => :user_id
```

The rating validation makes sure that a second rating is not accepted, but I need to change the associations (or the form) so that a second score option never appears.

My applicant form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :ratings do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :score, Rating::SCORES, :to_s, :humanize %> 
    <%= builder.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :applicant_id, :value => @applicant.id %>
<% end %>
```

How do I specify (in the applicant model, I'd guess, since that's the form I'm editing) that the applicant_id, user_id combo in the ratings table has to be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting things working by doing the following.

In my applicant controller, I changed the edit method to:

```
  def edit
    @applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
    @my_rating = Rating.where(:applicant_id => params[:id]).where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    if @my_rating.empty?
      @my_rating = @applicant.ratings.build
    end
  end
```

Since I can't make a scope using the current_user, I figured it would work here.  Then, in the form, I changed the nested attribute fields to:

```
<%= f.fields_for :ratings, @my_rating do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.collection_select :score, Rating::SCORES, :to_s, :humanize %> 
    <% if builder.object.user_id.nil?%>
        <%= builder.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The other important bit is the uniqueness validation in the ratings model above.  That made sure that each user could have only one rating per applicant.

This seems to work fine for me, but if anyone has suggestions on how to improve this, I'd love to hear them.